# With Form Antd, how to catch values change with setFieldValue()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd, codesandbox

I want to catch event from `setFieldValue()`, with Antd Form.

[CodeSandBox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-hugle-qwryjy?file=/src/App.js)

In this code, if you write on the Input, the functions `onFieldsChange` and `onValuesChange` will be triggered.

But if you click on the button click me, the function `setFieldValue()` is called to update the value of the Input, but the two function are not called.

Thank to anyone can help me.

## EDIT

This doesn't seem feasible...

**setFieldsValue do not trigger onFieldsChange or onValuesChange? 
 

It's by design. Only user interactive can trigger the change event. This design is aim to avoid call setFieldsValue in change event which may makes loop calling.**

[Antd Documentation about this](https://ant.design/components/form#setfieldsvalue-do-not-trigger-onfieldschange-or-onvalueschange)

Comment: There's no option to listen to field change if value is set using `form.setField...`. You can use useWatch hook to listen for all values which may not be the best for your usecase ` const values = Form.useWatch([], form);` or create an issue in antd github. I think it will be better to provide a subscribe method so we can listen for changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to trigger only `onFieldsChange` event when setting fields to form. Take a look [here](https://ant.design/components/form#why-does-onfieldschange-trigger-three-times-on-change-when-field-sets-rules).

You just need to add [`rules`](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-dynamic-rule) to form fields (yes, you will use it to validate form values) then call `form.validateFields` right after setting values:

```
<Form
  name="basic_form"
  form={form}
  // can be triggered by rule validation
  onFieldsChange={(changedFields, allFields) => {
    console.log("on fields change : ", changedFields, allFields);
  }}
  // only triggered on user actions
  onValuesChange={(changedValues, allValues) => {
    console.log("on values change : ", changedValues, allValues);
  }}
>
  <Form.Item
    name="input"
    rules={[{ required: true, message: "please fill" }]}
  >
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>
  <Button
    onClick={() => {
      form.setFieldValue("input", "TEST MESSAGE");
      // if you don't pass any field so all
      // available fields will be validated
      form.validateFields(["input"]);
    }}
  >
    click me
  </Button>
</Form>
```

The "problem" of this sollution is: `onFieldsChange` will be triggered more than one time wich is not so hard do handle.

Also [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bas-ptj655?file=/src/App.js:237-251) is a working codesandbox.

Hope this helps:)